# I need to find coincident sides of geometrical figures (triangles and rectangles)

Tags: java

I have a triangle and rectangle class. Every figure is defined by integers which represent the coordinates.
Ex: a triangle has 3 vertices a,b and c.
In the class triangle I have int ax =..., int ay =... int bx =... and so on.
In the rectangle class I have int ulx(which means up-leftX), int bry (bottom-rightY) and so on. Rectangle: 4 vertices which means 8 Integers (6 for triangles).
Then i have an ArrayList Triangle and ArrayList Rectangle.
How do i find if two FIGURES have a coincident side?

this is my triangle class

```
public class Triangle {

    String name;
    int ax;
    int ay;
    int bx;
    int by;
    int cx;
    int cy;

    public Triangolo (String name, int ax, int ay, int bx, int by, int cx, int cy) {

        this.name=name;
        this.ax=ax;
        this.ay=ay;
        this.bx=bx;
        this.by=by;
        this.cx=cx;
        this.cy=cy;
    }


}
```

Comment: Myself, I would create a Point class (or use the `java.awt.Point` class) and a Side class, one that has two Point instances. Give both decent equals and hashCode methods, the one in the Side class that doesn't care about Point order, give your polygons a `List<Side>`, and then test for side coincidence by iterating through both lists.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try